# jQuery Flot.js wrong dates in x axis

Tags: javascript, php, plot, timestamp, flot

I am having a silly issue .. I have read the following which pertain to creating dates as the bottom of a `plot` chart using `flot.js`.  However my problem persists.:

[how-to-plot-a-date-range-on-x-axis-in-flot-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199814/how-to-plot-a-date-range-on-x-axis-in-flot-charts)

[Understanding Date and Time in JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=Javascript%20timestamp%20returning%20Jan%2001&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS767US767&oq=Javascript%20timestamp%20returning%20Jan%2001&aqs=chrome..69i57.7743j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

And I am still having issues.

Here is my Javascript:

```
           var chart_plot_11_data = [

                [1199167200000, 0],[1201845600000, 0],[1204351200000, 0],[1207026000000, 0],[1209618000000, 0],[1212296400000, 0],[1214888400000, 0],[1217566800000, 0],[1220245200000, 0],[1222837200000, 0],[1225515600000, 59.95],[1228111200000, 719.4],[1230789600000, 0],[1233468000000, 119.9],[1235887200000, 59.95],[1238562000000, 59.95],[1241154000000, 59.95],[1243832400000, 0],[1246424400000, 0],[1249102800000, 0],[1251781200000, 0],[1254373200000, 239.8],[1257051600000, 59.95],[1259647200000, 59.95],[1262325600000, 119.9],[1265004000000, 0],[1267423200000, 0],[1270098000000, 359.7],[1272690000000, 0],[1275368400000, 0],[1277960400000, 0],[1280638800000, 119.9],[1283317200000, 0],[1285909200000, 59.95],[1288587600000, 59.95],[1291183200000, 119.9],[1293861600000, 119.9],[1296540000000, 119.9],[1298959200000, 119.9],[1301634000000, 59.95],[1304226000000, 0],[1306904400000, 59.95],[1309496400000, 0],[1312174800000, 0],[1314853200000, 0],[1317445200000, 0],[1320123600000, 59.95],[1322719200000, 0],[1325397600000, 119.9],[1328076000000, 0],[1330581600000, 119.9],[1333256400000, 59.95],[1335848400000, 59.95],[1338526800000, 59.95],[1341118800000, 0],[1343797200000, 0],[1346475600000, 119.9],[1349067600000, 119.9],[1351746000000, 0],[1354341600000, 59.95],[1357020000000, 59.95],[1359698400000, 119.9],[1362117600000, 119.9],[1364792400000, 119.9],[1367384400000, 0],[1370062800000, 0],[1372654800000, 0],[1375333200000, 0],[1378011600000, 59.95],[1380603600000, 59.95],[1383282000000, 0],[1385877600000, 0],[1388556000000, 0],[1391234400000, 0],[1393653600000, 59.95],[1396328400000, 59.95],[1398920400000, 0],[1401598800000, 359.7],[1404190800000, 1678.6],[1406869200000, 959.2],[1409547600000, 1798.5],[1412139600000, 239.8],[1414818000000, 59.95],[1417413600000, 239.8],[1420092000000, 179.85],[1422770400000, 299.75],[1425189600000, 539.55],[1427864400000, 119.9],[1430456400000, 419.65],[1433134800000, 119.9],[1435726800000, 179.85],[1438405200000, 299.75],[1441083600000, 359.7],[1443675600000, 479.6],[1446354000000, 59.95],[1448949600000, 239.8],[1451628000000, 419.65],[1454306400000, 419.65],[1456812000000, 959.2],[1459486800000, 539.55],[1462078800000, 959.2],[1464757200000, 419.65],[1467349200000, 239.8],[1470027600000, 299.75],[1472706000000, 419.65],[1475298000000, 479.6],[1477976400000, 539.55],[1480572000000, 419.65],[1483250400000, 1139.05],[1485928800000, 1258.95],[1488348000000, 2098.25],[1491022800000, 1139.05],[1493614800000, 599.5],[1496293200000, 779.35],[1498885200000, 899.25],[1501563600000, 899.25],[1504242000000, 359.7],[1506834000000, 299.75],[1509512400000, 299.75],[1512108000000, 359.7],[1514786400000, 479.6],[1517464800000, 899.25],[1519884000000, 1798.5],[1522558800000, 359.7],[1525150800000, 0],[1527829200000, 0],[1530421200000, 0],[1533099600000, 0],[1535778000000, 0],[1538370000000, 0],[1541048400000, 0],[1543644000000, 0],

            ];
            var chart_plot_11_settings = {
                series: {
                    curvedLines: {
                        apply: true,
                        active: true,
                        monotonicFit: true
                    }
                },
                colors: ["#26B99A"],
                grid: {
                    borderWidth: {
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        bottom: 1,
                        left: 1
                    },
                    borderColor: {
                        bottom: "#7F8790",
                        left: "#7F8790"
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    timeformat: "%b %m"
                }

            };
            if ($("#chart_plot_11").length) {

                $.plot($("#chart_plot_11"), [{
                    label: "Revenue",
                    data: chart_plot_11_data,
                    lines: {
                        fillColor: "rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.12)"
                    },
                    points: {
                        fillColor: "#fff"
                    }
                }], chart_plot_11_settings);

            }
```

Now the part I am particularly having issues with is :

```
 [1199167200000, 0],[1201845600000, 0],[1204351200000, ...
```

According to what I have read, a Unix timestamp needs to be multiplied by 1000 since Unix measures in seconds and JS in milliseconds.  So in my `php` that I return, this is how I am getting that timestamp:

```
$mysql_time = "$year-$month-01"; // Year IE(2017) - Month IE(05) - First day of month (01)
$info_by_month['timestamp'] = strtotime($mysql_time) * 1000;
```

Basically converting a mysql timestamp to a Unix timestamp, then multiplying by 1000 to get a JS timestamp.

Here is what it returns:
[image]

Problem is, they are all showing Jan 01 --  Is my problem in the `php`, or the `JS`?  How do I return the correct `timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the timeformat in the JS to something like `timeformat: "%b %m<br>%Y"` and you can see the year. Keep in mind that the dates on the x axis belong to the ticks and gridlines, not to the data points. See the code snippet for the result.

```js
var chart_plot_11_data = [

  [1199167200000, 0],
  [1201845600000, 0],
  [1204351200000, 0],
  [1207026000000, 0],
  [1209618000000, 0],
  [1212296400000, 0],
  [1214888400000, 0],
  [1217566800000, 0],
  [1220245200000, 0],
  [1222837200000, 0],
  [1225515600000, 59.95],
  [1228111200000, 719.4],
  [1230789600000, 0],
  [1233468000000, 119.9],
  [1235887200000, 59.95],
  [1238562000000, 59.95],
  [1241154000000, 59.95],
  [1243832400000, 0],
  [1246424400000, 0],
  [1249102800000, 0],
  [1251781200000, 0],
  [1254373200000, 239.8],
  [1257051600000, 59.95],
  [1259647200000, 59.95],
  [1262325600000, 119.9],
  [1265004000000, 0],
  [1267423200000, 0],
  [1270098000000, 359.7],
  [1272690000000, 0],
  [1275368400000, 0],
  [1277960400000, 0],
  [1280638800000, 119.9],
  [1283317200000, 0],
  [1285909200000, 59.95],
  [1288587600000, 59.95],
  [1291183200000, 119.9],
  [1293861600000, 119.9],
  [1296540000000, 119.9],
  [1298959200000, 119.9],
  [1301634000000, 59.95],
  [1304226000000, 0],
  [1306904400000, 59.95],
  [1309496400000, 0],
  [1312174800000, 0],
  [1314853200000, 0],
  [1317445200000, 0],
  [1320123600000, 59.95],
  [1322719200000, 0],
  [1325397600000, 119.9],
  [1328076000000, 0],
  [1330581600000, 119.9],
  [1333256400000, 59.95],
  [1335848400000, 59.95],
  [1338526800000, 59.95],
  [1341118800000, 0],
  [1343797200000, 0],
  [1346475600000, 119.9],
  [1349067600000, 119.9],
  [1351746000000, 0],
  [1354341600000, 59.95],
  [1357020000000, 59.95],
  [1359698400000, 119.9],
  [1362117600000, 119.9],
  [1364792400000, 119.9],
  [1367384400000, 0],
  [1370062800000, 0],
  [1372654800000, 0],
  [1375333200000, 0],
  [1378011600000, 59.95],
  [1380603600000, 59.95],
  [1383282000000, 0],
  [1385877600000, 0],
  [1388556000000, 0],
  [1391234400000, 0],
  [1393653600000, 59.95],
  [1396328400000, 59.95],
  [1398920400000, 0],
  [1401598800000, 359.7],
  [1404190800000, 1678.6],
  [1406869200000, 959.2],
  [1409547600000, 1798.5],
  [1412139600000, 239.8],
  [1414818000000, 59.95],
  [1417413600000, 239.8],
  [1420092000000, 179.85],
  [1422770400000, 299.75],
  [1425189600000, 539.55],
  [1427864400000, 119.9],
  [1430456400000, 419.65],
  [1433134800000, 119.9],
  [1435726800000, 179.85],
  [1438405200000, 299.75],
  [1441083600000, 359.7],
  [1443675600000, 479.6],
  [1446354000000, 59.95],
  [1448949600000, 239.8],
  [1451628000000, 419.65],
  [1454306400000, 419.65],
  [1456812000000, 959.2],
  [1459486800000, 539.55],
  [1462078800000, 959.2],
  [1464757200000, 419.65],
  [1467349200000, 239.8],
  [1470027600000, 299.75],
  [1472706000000, 419.65],
  [1475298000000, 479.6],
  [1477976400000, 539.55],
  [1480572000000, 419.65],
  [1483250400000, 1139.05],
  [1485928800000, 1258.95],
  [1488348000000, 2098.25],
  [1491022800000, 1139.05],
  [1493614800000, 599.5],
  [1496293200000, 779.35],
  [1498885200000, 899.25],
  [1501563600000, 899.25],
  [1504242000000, 359.7],
  [1506834000000, 299.75],
  [1509512400000, 299.75],
  [1512108000000, 359.7],
  [1514786400000, 479.6],
  [1517464800000, 899.25],
  [1519884000000, 1798.5],
  [1522558800000, 359.7],
  [1525150800000, 0],
  [1527829200000, 0],
  [1530421200000, 0],
  [1533099600000, 0],
  [1535778000000, 0],
  [1538370000000, 0],
  [1541048400000, 0],
  [1543644000000, 0],

];
var chart_plot_11_settings = {
  series: {
    curvedLines: {
      apply: true,
      active: true,
      monotonicFit: true
    }
  },
  colors: ["#26B99A"],
  grid: {
    borderWidth: {
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 1,
      left: 1
    },
    borderColor: {
      bottom: "#7F8790",
      left: "#7F8790"
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%b %m<br>%Y"
  }

};
if ($("#chart_plot_11").length) {

  $.plot($("#chart_plot_11"), [{
    label: "Revenue",
    data: chart_plot_11_data,
    lines: {
      fillColor: "rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.12)"
    },
    points: {
      fillColor: "#fff"
    }
  }], chart_plot_11_settings);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>

<div id="chart_plot_11" style="height: 320px;"></div>
```

Comment: Yup, there was nothing wrong with my syntax .. It was just showing Jan 01 of every year ...  Good catch!